# Email Template does not work with nested input objects (handlebar3 - mailgun)

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, handlebars.js, mailgun

For me it seems that templates does not work with nested input objects. What I mean by that consider the template:

This works fine

```
<p ">Your Cat Thanks You  {{name}}</p>
```

with variable:

```
{name:'joe'}
```

This does not work:

```
<p ">Your Cat Thanks You  {{personalInfo.firstName}} {{personalInfo.lastName}}</p>
```

with variable:

```
{personalInfo:{firstName:'John',lastName:'Doe'}}
```

I am using nodejs with mailgun-js libary with these options which seems to be fine:

```
const mailData= {from: "some shop <info@someshop.com>",
      to: "example@example.com",
      subject: "example",
      template: exampleTemplateName,
      ["h:X-Mailgun-Variables"]: JSON.stringify(exampleJson)}


mailgun({
  apiKey: api_key,
  domain: DOMAIN,
  host: "api.eu.mailgun.net"
}).messages().send(mailData)
```

Comment: Do you find a solution ?

Comment: Experiencing the same issue

Comment: got an solution already?